# How to translate this MSBuild script to F#/FAKE?

Tags: f#, msbuild, f#-fake

What is the translation of the following MSBuild script into F#/FAKE?

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> 
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CurrentMode>None</CurrentMode>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Compile_A">
        <Message Text="Hello from Compile_A" />

        <CallTarget Targets="SetToA"/>
        <CallTarget Targets="IntermediateStage"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Compile_B">
        <Message Text="Hello from Compile_B" />

        <CallTarget Targets="SetToB"/>
        <CallTarget Targets="IntermediateStage"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="IntermediateStage">
        <Message Text="Hello from IntermediateStage" />

        <CallTarget Targets="Compile"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Compile">
        <Message Text="Hello from Compile. I'm using $(CurrentMode)" />
    </Target>

    <!-- The following Targets are only necessary due to a MSBuild bug (CallTarget and CreateProperty cannot be combined) -->
    <Target Name="SetToA">
        <CreateProperty Value="A">
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="CurrentMode" />
        </CreateProperty>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="SetToB">
        <CreateProperty Value="B">
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="CurrentMode" />
        </CreateProperty>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

My main goal is to set a property in the topmost targets with different values (`CurrentMode` is either `A` or `B`) and consume it in the deepest target (`Compile`).

Comment: A FAKE script is just F#. You can set variables and fields wherever you like, including target functions.

Comment: That's right, but I have no clue how to implement the process of overwriting a property in F#

Comment: What are you trying to do though? A target that does different things based on a "mode" sounds a lot like a target that needs to be split into different targets, or a function that's called from different targets using different parameters

Comment: On the topmost level, I need two different entry points - mode A and B. In between, there is a lot of common logic that doesn't depend on the mode. On the deepest level, the compiler has to be called in a slightly different way depending on the mode.

Comment: That's what target chains are for. Create two different chains with the same steps, except those steps that need to work differently. Eg, `"Common1" ==> "Common2" ==> "StepA" ==> "Publish" ==> "MyProcessA"` is the same as `"Common1" ==> "Common2" ==> "StepB" ==> "Publish" ==> "MyProcessB"` except that `StepB` call. You can run different chains  easily eg with `fake build -t MyProcessB`. This will execute all dependencies one after the other

Comment: both in MSBuild and FAKE, instead of entry points with steps that follow, you have targets with *dependencies*. You ask for a specific target to run and the build system finds and executes all dependencies.

Comment: So you'd suggest to duplicate the compile step into a second target and the dependency graph as well? This seems a bit error-prone to me... whenever another target comes into, the developer must remember to register it in the second dependency graph

Comment: no, he'd only have to specify the dependency. That's how MSBuild works already. I'd suggest reading FAKE's tutorials before starting to use it, especially the parts that show how to define dependencies. Check [FAKE's own build script too](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/release/next/build.fsx#L1276). There are different chains for default building, different ones for testing, publishing. There are even [conditional steps](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/release/next/build.fsx#L1244)

Comment: The conditional step looks very interesting, thank you. How can I use it based on a property set by another target?

Comment: Why does it have to be set in a target? What is the value of the property based on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer will probably differ based on what is your actual scenario. In particular, you might not even need separate targets for the different steps of your process if you do not ever plan to run them separately (in which case, just using a function that takes the mode as a parameter and invoking that from `CompileA` and `CompileB` would work fine).

However, if you want to keep separate targets for all the steps, you could do something like this:

```
#load ".fake/build.fsx/intellisense.fsx"
open Fake.Core
open Fake.Core.TargetOperators

let mutable CurrentMode = "None"

Target.create "SetA" (fun _ ->
  CurrentMode <- "A"
)

Target.create "SetB" (fun _ ->
  CurrentMode <- "B"
)

Target.create "IntermediateStage" (fun _ ->
  printfn "In the intermediate stage"
)

Target.create "Compile" (fun _ ->
  printfn "Compiling using mode %s" CurrentMode
)

Target.create "CompileA" ignore
Target.create "CompileB" ignore

"SetA" ==> "CompileA"
"SetB" ==> "CompileB"
"IntermediateStage" ==> "Compile" ==> "CompileA"
"IntermediateStage" ==> "Compile" ==> "CompileB"
"SetA" ?=> "IntermediateStage"
"SetB" ?=> "IntermediateStage"

Target.runOrDefault "CompileA"
```

This uses mutable variable `CurrentMode` that is set by `SetA` or `SetB` targets (arguably, not very functional, but it captures what you're doing).

The dependencies between targets are specified using `==>`. Note that `SetA` has to happen before `CompileA` (and similar for B) and `IntermediateStage` needs to go before `Compile` which is pre-requisite for both kinds of compiles.

There is one subtle trick - you don't want to say that `SetA` and `SetB` are required for `IntermediateStep`, because then FAKE would run both in non-deterministic order. the `?=>` opreator lets you specify *soft dependencies* which say that if both `IntermediateStep` and `SetA` are to be executed, then `SetA` has to go first - so the last two lines are not adding dependencies, but making ordering explicit.